# calculate support of a rule in large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, optimization

```
df = pd.Series([["26"], ["81", "15", "27"], ["50"], ["8"], ["81", "15"], 
["10"], ["81"]]).to_frame(name='itemsets')


       itemsets
0          [26]
1  [81, 15, 27]
2          [50]
3           [8]
4      [81, 15]
5          [10]
6          [81]

rule = [["81"],["15"]]
```

i tried this but it's to slow because the dataset has 9 million lines, so i look for an efficient solution to perform this code with this solution it takes more than 4 seconds, is that a way to convert the dataframe to a numpy array or everything that performs this code ?

```
def support(rule):
    rule = rule[0] + rule[1]
    support = 0
    support = sum([set(rule)<=set(row) for row in df])
return support/SIZE

when i try it on the largest dataset which contains 9 million transactions the result is :

support(rule)
0.001039247773829178
```

the idea is to count the number of occurence of a non strict subset in a dataframe

Comment: Could you also provide your desired outcome and describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve?!

Comment: It's not clear what you want the result to be.

Comment: i edited the post could you see please

Comment: It's not clear how your function is applied across the series, or where `SIZE` is coming from. You should clearly outline the steps in the problem with the example dataset you've provided.

Comment: SIZE is the size of the entire dataset which is pandas dataframe SIZE is equal to 8286763

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

define `rule` as

```
rule = ['81', '15']

df.itemsets.apply(set).le(set(rule)).mean()

0.2857142857142857
```

---

## Numpy alternative

Should quicken things up

```
def support(rule, series):  
    n = len(series)  
    i = np.arange(n).repeat(series.str.len())
    out = np.ones(n, bool)
    np.logical_and.at(out, i, np.in1d(np.concatenate(series), rule))
    return out.mean()

support(rule, df.itemsets)

0.2857142857142857
```

Comment: it doesn't return the true value and it takes 5 seconds it's too slow and doesn't return the exact value

Comment: What do you mean "It doesn't return the true value"?  Your function returned a number.  As does mine.  If not the number, what did you want as the output?

Comment: when i tried your function on the dataset it doesn't . return the exact support of the rule

Comment: So that I can compare, what is the result or exact value given the input you provided?  Also, what is `SIZE`?  I assumed it was the length of the dataframe.

Comment: i tried with this rule ['24','25','20'] and it returns 0.011245645615785078 my solution is exact but too slow

Comment: With the same sample `df` you provided?  Or your larger dataset?  What is the result of running `rule = ['81', '15']` on the dataframe you provided?